# PHP - add values to already existing array

Tags: php

I have a already defined array, containing values just like the one below:

```
$arr = ['a','b','c'];
```

How could one add the following using PHP?

```
$arr = [
   'a' => 10,
   'b' => 5,
   'c' => 21
]
```

I have tried:
`$arr['a'] = 10` but it throws the error: `Undefined index: a`

I am surely that I do a stupid mistake.. could someone open my eyes?

Full code below:

```
$finishes = []; //define array to hold finish types
foreach ($projectstages as $stage) {
    if ($stage->finish_type) {
        if(!in_array($stage->finish_type, $finishes)){
            array_push($finishes, $stage->finish_type); 
        }
    }
}

foreach ($projectunits as $unit) {
    $data[$i] = [
        'id' => $unit->id,
        'project_name' => $unit->project_name,
        'block_title' => $unit->block_title,
        'unit' => $unit->unit,
        'core' => $unit->core,
        'floor' => $unit->floor,
        'unit_type' => $unit->unit_type,
        'tenure_type' => $unit->tenure_type,
        'floors' => $unit->unit_floors,
        'weelchair' => $unit->weelchair,
        'dual_aspect' => $unit->dual_aspect
    ];  
    $st = array();    
    $bs = '';     
    foreach ($projectstages as $stage) {
        $projectmeasure = ProjectMeasure::select('measure')
                ->where('project_id',$this->projectId)
                ->where('build_stage_id', $stage->id)
                ->where('unit_id', $unit->id)
                ->where('block_id', $unit->block_id)
                ->where('build_stage_type_id', $stage->build_stage_type_id)
                ->first();

        $st += [
            'BST-'.$stage->build_stage_type_id => ($projectmeasure ? $projectmeasure->measure : '0')
        ]; 
        
        if (($stage->is_square_meter == 0) && ($stage->is_draft == 0)) {
            $height = ($stage->height_override == 0 ? $unit->gross_floor_height : $stage->height_override); //08.14.20: override default height if build stage type has it's own custom height
            $st += [
                'BST-sqm-'.$stage->build_stage_type_id => ($projectmeasure ? $projectmeasure->measure * $height: '0')
            ]; 
            if ($stage->finish_type) {
                $finishes[$stage->finish_type] += ($projectmeasure ? $projectmeasure->measure * $height: '0') * ($stage->both_side ? 2 : 1); //error is thrown at this line
            }
        } else {
            if ($stage->finish_type) {
                $finishes[$stage->finish_type] += ($projectmeasure ? $projectmeasure->measure : '0');
            }
        }

    }
    $data[$i] = array_merge($data[$i], $st);
    $data[$i] = array_merge($data[$i], $finishes[$stage->finish_type]);
    $i++;
}
```

The above code is used as is and the array `$finishes` is the one from the first example, called `$arr`

Comment: _“I have tried: `$arr['a'] = 10` but it throws the error: `Undefined index: a`”_ - no it doesn’t: https://3v4l.org/7koaV

Comment: it does, that's why I am here. And the downvote is just rude..

Comment: Then provide an actual [mre] that shows the issue.

Comment: updated the code with the real example

Comment: Writing `$arr['a'] = 10` doesn't add value to `a` that you initialized in the first place. `a` IS the value of first element in array. If you write a line of code that you said is throwing exception, you'll just add key 'a' with value '10' to array that consists of `[0] => 'a', [1] => 'b', ...`.

Comment: You're using += in your real code instead of =. That tries to do maths to add to an existing value, whereas = can just assign the new index if it doesn't exist. It can't do maths to add a number to nothing. You need to check first if the index exists yet. If it doesn't exist, then assign it with an initial value. If it already exists with a value, then you can add the new value to the existing value.

Comment: Yes, using += will sum values, would that be the issue?

Comment: P.Sthe downvote is purely practical, to show the question wasn't clear. You said _"I have tried:$arr['a'] = 10"_ but when we see your real code, we learn that this isn't actually true at all. Details matter in programming.

Comment: Yes, the += is the issue. I've extended my comment above, take a look

Comment: Please add it in a answer, I'll vote for it, thank you!!!

Comment: P.S. that whole bit at the start `foreach ($projectstages as $stage) {
    if ($stage->finish_type) {
        if(!in_array($stage->finish_type, $finishes)){
            array_push($finishes, $stage->finish_type); 
        }
    }
}` appears to have no purpose, since later on you're just trying to change it anyway to a different structure. Was there a reason you needed it like that? None of the code you've shown makes use of that version.

Comment: there is a part of code not added that is pulling the data from the first $finishes array as it is

Comment: If I was you, I would use a different variable for that. A good basic rule of programming is "don't use the same variable for two different jobs". Right now you'll end up with a single array containing two separate data structures, which is just going to get confusing, or even cause bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `+=` in your real code instead of `=`. That tries to do maths to add to an existing value, whereas `=` can just assign a new index with that value if it doesn't exist.

`+=` can't do maths to add a number to nothing. You need to check first if the index exists yet. If it doesn't exist, then assign it with an initial value. If it already exists with a value, then you can add the new value to the existing value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the array of `strings` to a collection of `keys` (elements) and `values` (integers), you can try the following:

```
$arr = ['a','b','c'];
$newVals = [10, 5, 21];
function convertArr($arr, $newVals){
     if(count($arr) == count($newVals)){
          $len = count($arr);
          for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
               $temp = $arr[$i];
               $arr[$temp] = $newVals[$i];
               unset($arr[$i]);
          }
     }
     return $arr;
}
print_r(convertArr($arr, $newVals));
```

Output:

```
Array ( [a] => 10 [b] => 5 [c] => 21 )
```